# Error SA1500: Braces for multi-line statements should not share line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

> Error SA1500: Braces for multi-line statements should not share line

getting this  error on code

```
if (ObjItem != null)
{
    return new JsonResult(new
    {
        model = new ItemModel
        {
            Id = ObjItem.Id,
            ItemName = ObjItem.Name,
        },
        success = true
    });
}
```

how can we resolve this

Comment: There's only one brace in that code that shares a line with any other code so presumably that's the offending line and the solution is to make it not share that line with the other code.

Comment: First, be clear - this is a *code analysis warning*, not an error.

Comment: Change the line `});` or change the settings, so it won't complain about that (if you _want_ your code that way).

Comment: If you need more details: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1500.md

Answer (score 0):

Now the code in the question is correct, you can refer to it. We don't know how your previous code was written. If you encounter problems again, please attach a screenshot.

For this [SA1500](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1500.md) problem, you can refer to the official documentation. The example in the middle will clearly tell you the cause of the problem and the solution.